# Blender Shrink Wrap

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, shrinkwrap

Im learning car modeling currently and im new to blender. Im following as tutorial for modeling a wide body kit to a car.

This is the tutorial
https://youtu.be/Wj7ahpqGg5o

Im having issues with the shrink wrap modifier not working as presented in the video.
The blender version I'm using is 4.0

This is where im having issues
[image: This is where im having the issue]

In the video the shrink wrap is supposed to connect to the circle mesh when i extrude but its not doing it.

This is the video example and what its suppose to do.

[image: Youtube example]

I'm sorry if im all over the place, but is there any suggestions?

Comment: Hello could you please share the file (only the necessary objects, not the whole car)? https://blend-exchange.com/